# Paypal: How to get or create an invoice from a paid order

Tags: paypal

I'm new to paypal API, and I can't figure out how to create an order, then when it's paid get or create the related invoice to send it to the client?

Do I have to create a separate invoice ? if that's it, how can I link the new invoice to the previous order? And if I mark it as paid is it considerate as a new income ?

I can't find anything in the docs about that.

Thanks.

Comment: You normally use either orders _or_ invoices, not both. If you already have a PayPal order then you can simply charge the customer directly. It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish with both an order and an invoice?

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, 

I'm not quite used to paypal but usually  you create an order and when it's paid you generate the invoice/receipt and send it to the customer. An order is before the invoice. But maybe I'm not doing it the paypal way. If that's it what is the difference between an order and an invoice ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is a difference between PayPal and other uses of the term order. PayPal does not need or expect to be involved in the process of an "order" if you are not yet ready to bill or process payment. So you may have an agreement with a user which you call an order; that's fine, but you can leave PayPal out of it :). Creating an order in PayPal is a step you can take to collect agreement from your customer to be directly billed for the transaction. If you invoice customers, you don't need the direct billing permission, and vice versa.